# Access properties of 1 java bean in session using c:out tag

Tags: java, jsp, tags, jstl

I am trying to output text value of a property of a bean in session in a JSP. I need to output it between  tag. I am struck up on the syntax. Here is my code till now

```
<%EditTicketBean etlBean= (EditTicketBean)session.getAttribute("etBeanInServlet");
<textarea><c:out value = "${etlBean.ticketDesc}" />
```

However this does not work. If I use out.println it works

```
<textarea><%out.println(etlBean.getTicketDesc());%> </textarea>
```

What is the correct syntax for using this JSTL tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you mixing JSTL and scriplets? You can't access the variables set in scriplets, inside an EL. Better option is to avoid that scriplet alltogether, and just use EL, to access attributes from session.

You can directly use the EL expression:

```html
<textarea>${etBeanInServlet.ticketDesc}</textarea>
```

you can also explicitly specify that you are fetching the attribute from session scope (only when there is conflict between variables set in various scopes) like so:

```html
<textarea>${sessionScope.etBeanInServlet.ticketDesc}</textarea>
```

and finally using using JSTL `<c:out>` tag, which will escape XML for you:

```html
<textarea><c:out value="${etBeanInServlet.ticketDesc}" /></textarea>
```